# GridView databinding issue

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, windows-8

I have a trouble with GridView data binding.

I have created a View Model in ViewModelGV.cs file.

```
class ViewModelGV
{

    public ObservableCollection<Person> Persons{ get; set; }          

    public ViewModelGV()
    {
        Persons = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
        Person person1 = new Person();
        person1.Name = "John";
        Persons.Add(person1);

        Person person2 = new Person();
        person2.Name = "Jack";
        Persons.Add(person2);

        Person person3 = new Person();
        person3.Name = "Stephen";
        Persons.Add(person3);
    }
}
```

And another class of person with simple Name property.

```
class Person
{
    private String _Name;

    public String Name
    {
        get { return _Name; }
        set { _Name = value; }
    } 
}
```

Then in my XAML file I have pointed DataContext to my ViewModelGV (I have added some question marks to mark important points in code).

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <ViewModels:ViewModelGV/>
</Page.DataContext>
```

and added CollectionViewSource

```
<Page.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Name="Src" IsSourceGrouped="False" ItemsPath="?" Source="{Binding Persons}" />
</Page.Resources>
```

I have no idea how to point for the specific item Name value, it probably has something to do with ItemsPath attribute.

Then in my GridView I want to create a StackPanel with Rectangle and TextBlock underneath.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutGrid" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <GridView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Src}}">
        <GridView.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.Panel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="100" Height="100" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ? Name ? }" FontSize="40" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.Panel>
            </GroupStyle>
        </GridView.GroupStyle>
    </GridView>   
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Persons.Count}" Margin="0,200,0,0"></TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

Here is the result which shows proper count but unproper template and Person Data

[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Person.Name}" FontSize="40" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar recently and had it working. Try changing your xaml to the following

```
<GridView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Persons, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

and

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="40"/>
```

I didn't use a collection view source and just bound directly to the observable collection within my view model. Hope this helps.